# Caching all users in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, memory, caching, distributed-caching

I am working on a web app in ASP.NET/C# which needs to be scalable to handle the high user load (will probably run in a web farm). Since it will cater to a high number of users, around 1 Million plus, but number of online users would be around 30K-50K. I plan to use caching (provider based), and was wondering:

1. Is it a good idea to cache ALL users for performance? I plan to cache all other generic data, like settings etc, but how efficient would it be to cache ALL users in memory? If a user changes his/her profile, I will reload only that particular user in cache (having a collection of all the users). Any suggestions on this approach?
2. Do I need to worry about locking when using this above users cache? Only one editing the profile would be the user himself, that would be one atomic operation, though there will be multiple read oeprations in different threads. So while fetching users from cache, or updating a particualr user, should I use lock?

Thanks

Asif

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting anything in Global Cache that is only useful to a single user is usually a bad idea and a performance killer. Optimize your database queries, and you will be in much better shape.

As a general rule of thumb you should only keep things in cache that are expensive to get from the database, and more than one user will want to see that information at once. Such as a list of the top 100 products or something. Small amounts of data that are relatively cheap to grab from the database, and that are only useful to a single person should stay where they are.

Caching increases complexity tremendously, and even more so in a web farm. Don't introduce needless complexity unless you absolutely have to. Wait until you have an *actual* performance problem before trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Caching users is probably a good idea. But it depends on how much data you are going to cache for each user, and the cost of retrieving that data from wherever it is stored.

For locking - can anyone else edit a user's profile (like an admininstrator)? Would that be a common occurrence? If so, you may want to do some locking. Otherwise, if only the user can edit their own stuff, I wouldn't bother.